# Flash : Font larger in one file and smaller in other

Tags: flash, fonts, size

I have two files.  Both have some dynamic fields, and some static fields.  They both use the same two fonts.  I need to embed both fonts.  When I generate the size report, one font is 15K larger than the other.  The only difference between the two embeddings is the % sign.  I took it out, and it did not make a noticeable difference.

I noticed, in fixing these files, the original developer had chosen "Graphic" from the properties pulldown instead of MovieClip.  I believe I have changed them all to Movie Clip, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Why is one file so much bigger than the other?

Here are the two size reports.

```
Font Name        Bytes         Characters
-------------    ----------    ----------
Gotham-Medium         22727     ,.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ’
Gotham-Bold            4828     .0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 

Font Name        Bytes         Characters
-------------    ----------    ----------
Gotham-Medium         20986     ,.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ’
Gotham-Bold           20945     %.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Thank You

Comment: Here's some more weirdness.  I took out numbers and lowercase for the Bold font, and made sure there was only one font, per font box, and it not only reduced the Bold font file size, but also the Medium font.